# When creating a new Empty MVC3 Web Application, is there a way to exclude EntityFramework?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, new-project

Whenever I create a new Empty MVC3 Web Application project in Visual Studio 2010 SP1, it automatically adds EntityFramework and some other packages by default. This is rather annoying when I don't use EntityFramework, nor do I use some of the other items that are "pre-installed" by VS.

Is there a way to customize the project template, without creating a whole new template, so that it doesn't add these by default?

Comment: Phil Haack made [A Really Empty ASP.NET MVC 3 Template](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/11/a-really-empty-asp-net-mvc-3-project-template.aspx), which takes out a lot of other stuff; too. You can use that, or fork it to customize it a bit more. Either way it's a new template.

Comment: @vcsjones, awesome!! I think that's exactly what I was looking for. If you add it as an answer, I'll mark it as being correct since it satisfies myself not having to create a new template. Thanks!

Comment: Darin posted the same thing; I'd just accept his.

Comment: I didn't even look at his link because it was titled 'create your own template' which wasn't what I was wanting to do, I didn't realize he posted a link to the same Phil Haack post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you could [create your own template](http://haacked.com/archive/2012/01/11/a-really-empty-asp-net-mvc-3-project-template.aspx) and get rid of all the crap (such as EntityFramework) you don't need.

Comment: right, I understand that. Which was why I specifically asked if there was a way to do it without creating a whole new template. If there was an easier way to do it without having to create my own, I would prefer that

Comment: I apologize, I didn't even look at your link because of the way it was titled and I had no intention of creating my own template, I was looking for something out of the box like vcsjones posted in the comments, but then he pointed out what you also linked to the Phil Haack post, so I will accept yours based on vcsjones pointing that out to me